# Directly Solve this IVP DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-transforms

For $0<a<1$, directly solve the IVP:
$$f''(x) - 3f'(x) + 2f(x) = k\delta(x-a)$$
$$f(0) = f'(0) = 1$$

Where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function and $k$ is a real number.

I can attain the complementary function easily, and get $Ae^x + Be^{2x}$ for arbitrary $A$ and $B$, but I'm having difficulties with finding the particular integral.

Comment: Variation of parameters should do the trick.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks!